# Determining limits for a closed integration.

Tags: calculus, integration, contour-integration

I want to integrate a function over a closed circle in the following region.
$$\oint f(x) dx + f(y)dy$$
$$^2 + ^2 ≤ 1$$
$$ ≥ $$
$$ ≥ 0$$

How do I determine the limits for the integration?
I know that the first equation is a unit circle.

Answer (score 0):

Answer to the first version of the question:

You have the limits $y=x$ and $x^2 + y^2 = 1$ which gives you $x=y= \frac12 \sqrt 2$ as the integration limit. So you integrate

$$
\int_{x=0}^{\frac12 \sqrt 2}dx \int_{y=x}^{\sqrt{1 - x^2}}dy f(x,y)
$$

Comment: Do we not have to find radial limits?

Comment: The question was phrased in $(x,y)$ so I expected you wanted limits in $(x,y)$.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to Stack. I eddied the question. Would the limits still be the same?